# Help on diivergence in the Paired T Test sample size formula between Machin and others

Tags: t-test, sample-size, paired-data, clinical-trials

for a pre-post study, continous endpoint (assume normality). I would like to detect a difference of 50 (mg/dL) and SD of the changes could be easily 20 mg/dL (for ex.). the issue is, according to machin et al,
N pairs = 2*(Z1-a/2+Zb)^2/effect size^2. + correction factor. Basically, looks like a 2 sample T test, but SD is the within (smaller than total SD in a parallel study).I have seen this approach in another book. On the other hand, i have seen sample size calculations with the formula without the 2 in the numerator. I guees that the first approach ask genuinely about differences in means between 2 conditions (2 drugs in crossover or 2 times in pre-post) and the Sample is smaller due to the smaller variance, while the second is more a one sample T test being the null 0? whichs the desired approach and whichs correct? or if both correct, whichs the difference in statements? I have seen both approachs in pre post, and I think crossovers (forgetting period effect etc). Its relevant because N is half for the second approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a parallel design you'd measure $y$ in two groups of subjects $a$ and $b$ to produce $\bar y_a$ and $\bar y_b$, and the difference of interest might be $\bar y_a - \bar y_b$. In a 2x2 cross-over you'd measure each subject *twice*, once under each of the conditions, so you get $\bar y_{a1}$ and $\bar y_{b2}$ for the subjects that first received $a$ and then $b$, and $\bar y_{b1}$ and $\bar y_{a2}$ for the other group. The mean difference of interest now becomes:
$$\bar y_a - \bar y_b=\frac{1}{2}(\bar y_{a1}+\bar y_{a2})-\frac{1}{2}\big(\bar y_{b1}+\bar y_{b2})=\frac{1}{2}(\bar y_{a1}+\bar y_{a2}-\bar y_{b1}-\bar y_{b2})$$

Assuming you have $n$ subjects and put $\frac{n}{2}$ in each group, the common variance of the parallel estimate would be $\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2} = \frac{4\sigma^2}{n}$. The variance of the cross-over estimate however is:

$$
\frac{1}{4}(\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n/2})=\frac{2\sigma^2}{n}
$$

Using the same total $n$ (but measuring each subject twice!) you have half the variance in a cross-over setting compared to parallel. This even ignores the fact that  the parallel variance is between-subject whereas cross-over is within; the latter is usually smaller.

In your particular setting you want to compare pre and post measurements. I'm assuming this cannot be a 2x2 cross-over, because you can't have half of the subjects do their post measurement first and then their pre. However, instead of having to divide your groups into pre and post, you do get all $n$ measurements from both conditions, and you will be able to use the within- rather than the between-subject variance. It therefore doesn't matter which formula you use, as long as you know how they expect their parameters.

Specifically, a parallel-arm comparison usually takes $n$ as the number *per group*, so you can enter that as your total number of subjects. You can also use the cross-over formula and provide half of your total subjects as sample size.

Comment: Thanks! So, the first formula accounts for the total number of patients, with 2 measurements per patient (pre and post or 2 treatments after sequence allocation). The simpler formula without the '2' gives patients/arm in a crossover design. With a= 5%, b= 20%, d =0.33, SD =1.26, Machin's suggests a sample size of 254 pairs = total number of patients, 2 measures each, either in pre-post or half of them allocated to each sequence in 2x2 crossover. Simple formula gives half = patients in each "arm", so *2 = total sample size right?

Comment: @AlexOrtega using those numbers I get to $n=229$ for a t-test (using R's `power.t.test`), so that would be the total number of subjects you need to measure both pre & post to achieve the specified $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: pwr.t.test(d=0.26,sig.level = 0.05, power=0.80, type="paired",alternative = "two.sided")

     Paired t test power calculation 

              n = 118.0425
              d = 0.26
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number of *pairs*--> maybe here it comes the misunderstood? here means only one "measure"? so i should x2= and would get me the number or patients with both measures? But in that case it would be n=238, so which function did you use? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @AlexOrtega you used SD=1 and delta=0.26 in that call, not 1.26 and 0.33 as you said before. The question is also whether you want to test each subject's pre vs. its post (paired, as you did - nothing wrong with that & more efficient) or the *mean* of pre scores vs. the *mean* of post scores (two independent samples, which is what I did). For SD=1.26 and delta=0.33, measuring $n=116$ subjects twice (232 observations total) and using a paired t-test should give you 80% power.

Comment: So, which’s the most scientifically sound approach for a pre-post study (or crossover)? The approach by Machin gives 229 (438 observations) which is the one-arm calculation of a 2-sample T test. Nevertheless he shows the formula of a paired analysis (μd = Σd / N(pairs), and σd = √[Σ(d - μd)² / (n-1)]. Shouldn’t this approach be analyzed by an independent T Test? In the true “paired” (one-sample) approach, observations and sample are decreased to the half. Note, in statstodo.com, the latter is used but says “The results is the sample size in each of the 2 groups, assuming that they are equal”.

Comment: You can probably justify this being a paired design, although you may want to correct for the actual pre value (i.e. perform a baseline-corrected linear model rather than a simple t-test).

Comment: A linear model with no factor or with time period as factor? all patients are receiving the intervention, BR and thanks!